# Is there any way for connecting to a wireless Wi-Fi AP from a Linux PC avoiding the discovery fase (probe request/response)?

Tags: linux, wifi

I would like to switch between APs in the same network, with the lowest downtime possible. I saw a lot of analytic papers, which show that the discovery phase is the one which contributes more to the downtime.

Is there any tool which allows to connect to a specific BSSID directly, without performing this task, by getting as arguments the 802.11x protocol, the channel number and other information usually obtained from the discovery phase (or by caching this information from past associations)?

I tried some tools (nmcli, wpa_cli...), but I get downtimes higher than 4 seconds... It would be great to reduce this numbers down to 1 second or less.

Comment: Debian or RedHat?

Comment: You can force frequencies as in `pre-up iwconfig wlan0 freq 5.3G` (from my config). You might also force using a particular BSSID/SSID. However it is part of the protocol being slow, and often you might not do it at first time. There are no miracles, and there is also distance and noise. This is not a Unix problem, it is a WiFi protocol problem.